# Adding and Removing data from arrays and how to use that with conditional rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So, I have four item rendered on screen in RN by which when ever user clicks on a item it will change color and when ever he re clicks on it then it will change to its default color. So as i have four items, i need push them into an array in order to hold the clicked values. Now the problem I have used Set to make a unique array when user clicks, how to use this array for conditional rendering to change color of the item ? And also how to pop out the item in array when user reclicks it ??

My Set code:

```
onDepaturePress(time){
        this.setState({ time : [...new Set(this.state.TimeSource), time] })
    }
```

My item which needs to change color

```
<TouchableOpacity 
       onPress={() => this.onDepaturePress(item.time)}
             style={{ width: 50 }}>
             <Feather name={item.icon} size={35} style={this.state.TimeSource === item.time ? { color: 'red' } : { color: '#000' }} />
 </TouchableOpacity>\
```

From the above, i need to change color when user clicks on it again, and in short words when user clicks on all the four items one by one then all the items should change its color and when user re clicks it should re change to default

Comment: Why you are using Set? You can directly save the clicked value in your time array. This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/64065692/3784556

Comment: Wont that create duplicate datas when pushing into array ? thats why used Set

Comment: Could you please explain your use-case here? Why do you need to push array? Can't you directly save the clicked value to the ```item``` and then grab which ones were selected and do the other task?

Comment: As said, am not selecting one item like checkbox either checked or not checked. If user wish he can select all the four or three or two or one ! if he selects all the four then we need to change the color to all the four, in this case am using flatlist to display all the four items.